# Charset issue when uploading text file to AWS S3 through plUpload and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unicode, character-encoding, amazon-s3, paperclip

In my application, I am allowing users to upload files through plUpload library. On the server side, I am using paperclip for handling the uploaded files. My storage location is on Amazon S3.

I have a text file which contains Japanese and some special characters in it. If I upload this file to S3, its content-type will be `text/plain`. When I click on the direct link to that file on S3, my browser (Chrome) open a new tab and display the content directly in that tab. However, I think that because of this content-type, the browser can not display the correct character inside that content.

I tried using Trello for uploading and I realize that the file uploaded to S3 through their server is returned with `content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` (notice that they have the `charset=utf-8` part in their content-type)

My question is: how can I get my text file to be return with the header `content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Here is an example of the content in my text file. Pay attention to the first character, it is a special symbol and it is the reason which prevent the browser from displaying this file content correctly. If I removed that symbol, everything would be all right

> ※添付のデザインは、あくまで試案です。最近の潮流のシンプルなデザインにしてみました。

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this by override Paperclip UploadedFileAdapter like this (in `config/initializers/paperclip.rb`)

```
module Paperclip
  class UploadedFileAdapter < AbstractAdapter
    def initialize(target)
      @target = target

      cache_current_values

      if @target.respond_to?(:tempfile)
        @tempfile = copy_to_tempfile(@target.tempfile)
      else
        @tempfile = copy_to_tempfile(@target)
      end
    end

    class << self
      attr_accessor :content_type_detector
    end

    private

    def cache_current_values
      self.original_filename = @target.original_filename
      @content_type = determine_content_type
      @size = File.size(@target.path)
    end

    def content_type_detector
      self.class.content_type_detector
    end

    def determine_content_type
      content_type = @target.content_type.to_s.strip
      if content_type_detector
        content_type = content_type_detector.new(@target.path).detect
      end

      #NOTE: override paperclip, need to set the utf-8 for text file
      content_type = "text/plain; charset=utf-8" if content_type == "text/plain"

      content_type
    end
  end
end

Paperclip.io_adapters.register Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter do |target|
  target.class.name.include?("UploadedFile")
end
```